# Python - remove parts of a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have many fill-in-the-blank sentences in strings,

e.g. `"6d) We took no [pains] to hide it ."`

How can I efficiently parse this string (in Python) to be

```
"We took no to hide it"?
```

I also would like to be able to store the word in brackets (e.g. "pains") in a list for use later. I think the regex module could be better than Python string operations like split().

Comment: You _can't !_ unless you know what it is you are looking for. If you give some details on what form/shape/position relationships there are. English does not go easily from one form to another. As an example, you can't even parse an English sentence.. can't be done without a huge acronym library.

Comment: @sln Nothing in the question requires knowledge of English grammar, just an ability to identify square brackets.

Comment: @chepner - Just joking, really. So, What part of `6d) We took no [pains] to hide it ` looks like the sentence to extract?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you all the words inside the brackets.

```
import re
s="6d) We took no [pains] to hide it ."
matches = re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', s)
```

Then you can run this to remove all bracketed words.

```
re.sub('\[(.*?)\]', '', s)
```

Comment: This is perfect! +1 for matching it the non greedy way

Comment: This is great for getting the sentence removing the bracketed word, but I also asked how to remove the number and parenthesis from the beginning of the string. To do this... `re.sub('\[(.*?)\]', '', s).split(')')[1]`

Answer (score 2):

just for fun (to do the gather and substitution in one iteration)

```
matches = []
def subber(m):
    matches.append(m.groups()[0])
    return ""

new_text = re.sub("\[(.*?)\]",subber,s)
print new_text
print matches
```

Comment: Nice answer, but you could have started off in a better way than *just for fun* :D

Comment: @BhargavRao I agree, this is actually pretty good, not just fun.

Comment: everything i do is *just for fun* ... sometimes i even get a paycheck for it :P

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

s = 'this is [test] string'
m = re.search(r"\[([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\]", s)
print m.group(1)
```

Output

```
'test'
```

Answer (score 0):

For your example you could use this regex:

```
(.*\))(.+)\[(.+)\](.+)
```

You will get four groups that you can use to create your resulting string and save the 3. group for later use:

1. `6d)`
2. `We took no`
3. `pains`
4. `to hide it .`

I used `.+` here because I don't know if your strings always look like your example. You can change the `.+` to alphanumeric or sth. more special to your case.

```
import re

s = '6d) We took no [pains] to hide it .'
m = re.search(r"(.*\))(.+)\[(.+)\](.+)", s)

print(m.group(2) + m.group(4)) # "We took no  to hide it ."
print(m.group(3))              # pains
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
m = re.search(".*\) (.*)\[.*\] (.*)","6d) We took no [pains] to hide it .")
if m:
    g = m.groups()
    print g[0] + g[1]
```

**Output :**

We took no to hide it .